# Regex for openfootball

Tags: regex, perl

Exists string

```
(1) Thu Jun/12 17:00   Brazil 3-1 (1-1) Croatia       @ Arena de São Paulo, São Paulo (UTC-3)
```

I use regex:

```
/^\((\d+)\)\s(.*?)\s{2,}(.+?)\ (\d+)-(\d+)\ \(.*?\)\ (.+?)\s{2,}.*UTC-(\d+)/
```

How to modify regex, that passing also matches without first time result:

```
(1) Thu Jun/12 17:00   Brazil 3-1 Croatia       @ Arena de São Paulo, São Paulo (UTC-3)
```

?

Upd:

```
$1=1
$2=Thu Jun/12 17:00
$3=Brazil
$4=3
$5=1
$6=Croatia
$7=3
```

Comment: I read before and after the update, and still don't understand the question.

Comment: I need regexp, which work for two strings in question

Comment: Please ask your question in sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the first time result optional:

```
/^\((\d+)\)\s(.*?)\s{2,}(.+?) (\d+)-(\d+) (?:\(.*?\) )?(.+?)\s{2,}.*UTC-(\d+)/
#                                         ^^^________^^
```

Answer (score 1):

A set of progressive matches would probably turn out more legible / maintainable, but at least by adding the /x modifier we can allow for insignificant whitespace, which permits formatting of the regex to make it easier to read and understand.

Here's one way to do it:

```
my @targets = (
  q{(1) Thu Jun/12 17:00   Brazil 3-1 (1-1) Croatia       @ Arena de São Paulo, São Paulo (UTC-3)},
  q{(1) Thu Jun/12 17:00   Brazil 3-1 Croatia       @ Arena de São Paulo, São Paulo (UTC-3)}
);

foreach my $target ( @targets ) {

print "($1)($2)($3)($4)($5)($6)($7)\n"
  if $target =~ m/
                  ^\(([^)]+)\)\s+                           # 1
                  (\w{3}\s\w{3}\/\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2})\s+   # Date and Time
                  (\D+?)\s+                                 # Team A
                  (\d+)-(\d+)\s+                            # Score A - B
                  (?:\([^)]+\)\s+)?                         # Optional
                  (.+?)\s+@                                 # Team B
                  .+\(UTC-(\d+)\)$                          # TZ
                /x;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
(1)(Thu Jun/12 17:00)(Brazil)(3)(1)(Croatia)(3)
(1)(Thu Jun/12 17:00)(Brazil)(3)(1)(Croatia)(3)
```